# does SWITCHING FMTONLY impacts performance. inside stored procedure? (entity framework)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am building a dynamic query and trying to execute it using **sp_executesql** . I am using EF(entity framework) as my ORM tool. as i have read , entity framework initially set **FMTONLY to OFF first** and then only requesting metadata for that sql procedure ..

I AM not knowing the **impacts of using set fmtonly in sql** , ***if for only while creating complex type i set fmtonly to ON and after creating complex type inside EF i will again set its to OFF.  is it ok to use it like this?***

does that impact performance on next procedure call ?

what if i have done it already and wants to rollback..?..

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. Using `FMTONLY` is riddled with problem. Because when FMTONLY is ON a procedure executes *every* branch the results are often unexpected.

Since during development you know exactly what procedure you're calling and what is the expected result set, there is never a need to use FMTONLY on a well executed dev cycle. The fact that EF does it is by no means good practice.

Comment: what if i have done it already and wants to rollback..?.. can u explain more on what FMTONLY  does

Comment: if for only while creating complex type i set fmtonly to ON and after creating complex type inside EF i will again set its to OFF. is it ok to use it like this?

Comment: `FMTONLY` is used by tools that accept an arbitrary SQL and need to understand the shape of the result set returned (number, type and name of columns) *whitout actually executing the SQL*. Unless you create a design time SQL tool (eg. EF itself, not an app based on EF) you pretty much never have any need  to use `FMTONLY` in your code.